# DRCSIM ROS Topics Synchronization

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

Is there any mechanism to efficiently synchronize DRCSIM ROS topics? In a real robot the synchronization would happen with the control system tick. However, as the clock, force sensors, joint states, etc...  update at the "same time" i cannot be sure that all the other variables have already being updated when triggering my control with clock callback.

Best regards,

LR

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1544/drcsim-ros-topics-synchronization./) by [Luis Filipe Rossi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/55/luis-filipe-rossi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-02-27**:
I posted a question to answers.ros  http://answers.ros.org/question/56258/how-can-i-post-to-ross-callbackqueue/  trying to get around this issue.  Waiting and testing to see that all data is received and processed before doing controls calculations is fraught with peril, and will likely cause significant issues due to latency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I suspect this will take care of this issue:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/137/create-an-atlasstatesmsg-aggregating-all/diff

---

Originally posted by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) with karma: 298 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-04-02**:
it's been further updated to https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/169/add-atlas-atlas_command-and-atlas, as the originally proposed state message gets fragmented.